# AngularJs is empty list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I make simple program with .net Core and AngularJs + webApi
My Api code as below
There is no Js error after running the problem is factory return nothing.
when I set break point on  $location.qwets = index.query(); my "qwets" is empty the length of  "qwets" is 0.
The get method is working each time page refresh but result is nothing.

> I changed the code now I have results in 'qwets' but index is still empty

Thank you

```
// GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<ApplicationUser> {
            new ApplicationUser {Id="test", Email="test1@test.com" },
            new ApplicationUser {Id="tst2",Email="test2@test.com" }

        };
    }
```

app.js File is

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('saniehhaApp', [
    // Angular modules 
    //'ngRoute'

    // Custom modules  
    "indexService"
    // 3rd Party Modules

]);
})();
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('saniehhaApp')
    .controller('indexController', indexController);

indexController.$inject = ['$location', 'index'];

function indexController($location, index) {
    index.query()
    .$promise.then(function (result) {
     $scope.qwets = result;
}
})();
(function () {
'use strict';
var indexService = angular.module('indexService', ['ngResource']);

indexService.factory('index', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
     return $resource('/api/index/', {}, {
         query:
             {
                 method: 'GET',
                 params: {},
                 isArray: true
             }
     });
}]);
})();
```

and my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="saniehhaApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>SampleTest</title>

<script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
<div ng-controller="indexController"></div>
<h2>list of users</h2>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="qwet in qwets">
        <p> "{{qwet.Id}}" - {{qwet.Email}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab in developer bar and see if the API call is returning expected data? May be paste the response data in the question?

Comment: What you are describing is default `$resource` behavior. The request is asynchronous so `$resource` initially returns an empty array which then gets populated when request completes. Unless you need to do something immediately in the controller when data arrives it shouldn't be a problem...watchers in the view would still update things like ng-repeat

Comment: Problem is using `$location` and not `$scope`

Comment: @sabithpocker Yes I checked the network the api returned value.

Comment: @charlietfl its not helped. Thank you

Comment: create a demo in plunker that reproduces problem. Can get all the angular files from cdn for a demo and use a static json file for `$resource` to get

Comment: @patryk-Łucka its helped me and I can see the value the problem is nothing shown in Index.html

Comment: Also are you declaring a controller in your routing config as well as in `ng-controller`?

Comment: @charlietfl  now I use this code

Comment: no idea what that means to be honest

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/wYNV4nUPcRCEEqfnrwps/

Comment: @charlietfl I changed the code. now my $scope.qwets is not empty but index is empy. No I don not add controller in route.This webApi with static html file

Comment: don't understand what index is empty means when index is what is used to populate `$scope.qwets`

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you. I found another problem. Bad end Div. ng-repeat not in the div controller

Comment: oh yes...big issue there. No controller scope for your repeater

Comment: @charlietfl thank you another problem is "Scope" instead of "location" thank you

Comment: works here with simplified data and some syntax bug fixes that were cause by a plunker bug when switching to edit mode https://plnkr.co/edit/b2vMdFA4cxSSrNveUDYQ?p=preview

Comment: Note that promise not needed as mentioned above and seen in demo i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$location` and not `$scope` in the controller to assign properties needed in the view. The view doesn't see things in `$location`

Change to

```
function indexController($scope, index) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    $scope.qwets = index.query();
}
```

As mentioned in comments above, $resource will initially return an empty array (or object) that will subsequently be populated when the actual request completes and internal watchers will then update view when it arrives

> Also bad end "div" in HTML ng-repeat not in div controller